# Error with SDK package download in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, failed-installation

> java.io.IOException: Cannot download  , response: 200 OK Warning: An
>   error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository:
>   Cannot download  , response: 200 OK. java.io.IOException: Cannot
>   download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-3833124.zip':
>   dl.google.com Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package
>   Android Emulator: Cannot download
>   'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-3833124.zip':
>   dl.google.com. java.io.IOException: Cannot download ' Warning: An
>   error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Repository: Cannot
>   download

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955241/android-studio-installation-bug/50662641#50662641

Answer (score 77):

I had this similar issue below worked for me.
The solution for this is:

1. Run Android Studio as Administrator.
2. Re run the update.

It will work.

Comment: For me, on mac 10.13.6, it does not work for me when I sudo ./studio under /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: Oh my. That is cool. It worked for me on windows 10 64bit. Right click 'Android studio' icon, select 'run with admin'. 
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same issue on a Jenkins Slave that builds an apk from source code. Any idea how to solve it there?

Comment: did not worked for me

Answer (score 47):

delete uncompleted download in "[Android SDK folder]\.downloadIntermediates". i solved my problem by this method.

Comment: for windows its in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: for me its on C:\Users\youruser\.android\cache

Comment: did not worked for me

Answer (score 6):

you can manual download  sdk:

1. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-29_r04.zip
2. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/3534162-studio.sdk-patcher.zip
3. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r29.0.3-windows.zip
4. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6306047.zip
5. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-29_r01.zip
6. https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r29.0.6-windows.zip

Unpack to

1. C:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-2
2. C:\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4
3. C:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3
4. C:\Android\Sdk\emulator
5. C:\Android\Sdk\sources\android-29
6. C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Parsing

1. C:\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\package.xml
2. C:\Android\Sdk\emulator\package.xml
3. C:\Android\Sdk\patcher\v4\package.xml
4. C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\package.xml
5. C:\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\package.xml
6. C:\Android\Sdk\sources\android-29\package.xml

Comment: Note that this is not the recommended way of downloading the SDK.
Also from the OPs error message it looks like he has a general network issue to dl.google.com which makes this answer useless to him

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar problem.

And I notice some setting about **Force https//... to be fetched using http://...**

After using it, my download run normally:

[image]

Comment: I had same problem on windows 10. I tried this solution in conjunction with running android studio as an administrator, as recommended by @user7940775. I also had to switch from my secure network to mobile data. Not sure which one helped but i was able to install successfully.

Answer (score 2):

run the studio.sh script with sudo:

"sudo ./studio.sh"

if that does not work run:

"sudo chmod 777 -R /opt"

without quotes
should work

Answer (score 2):

Find Android SDK folder. (Usually `C:\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`) Delete folders which starts with dot(**.**), they are temporary download files. Then delete Android Emulator from SDK Manager. Then run Android Studio as administrator and then download and install Android Emulator again. Now you can create emulator and use it without errors.

Comment: I solved my problem in this way.. Because Android emulator sdk was uncompleted... (To Moderator: Dont delete my answer.. It is useful and working solution)

Comment: N Droidev, you are right, I solved this issue by your solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Very often the cause of errors can be an interruption of the Internet connection.
Just resume downloading with stable Internet.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the android SDK video ./studio.sh has to be run, however if run without sudo or su, this might give problems like these. So you should run with sudo or su as shown below:

- sudo ./studio.sh(or /path/to/studio.sh)

or if you want to run as root

- su
- Password:root password
- ./studio.sh or (or /path/to/studio.sh)
  This should fix the problem
  There might be a problem with /tmp if it is on a different partition and the partition has less space than needed to install

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please consider using proper formatting of code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had Admin access on my Laptop, but still I faced this problem (also other packages were getting downloaded). I found of that the https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip file is quiet large, and in my case since my network speed was slow and I was attempting to download a large file on a slow network I concluded that it was failing for timeout. I switched to a faster LAN and it got downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I downloaded problematic file 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-3833124.zip' and extracted it to
C:\Users\$usrname$\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android.
It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced a similar issue... Turn's out that may be related to system configuration of your machine..

Try downloading latest packages as per your system configuration from below:

https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwj9LkBRDnARIsAGQ-hUfGD0_yGXcqqZBN6d1Y-nMZ-TNKZtvdRBHimcE8m0tPYjyUw_bV77AaAsdzEALw_wcB

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while installing in Mac Catalina:

> java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out  (Read failed) Warning:
>   An error occurred while preparing SDK  package Sources for Android 29:
>   Operation timed  out (Read failed).

First attempt using standard configuration - **Failed**
Second attempt using standard configuration - **Failed**
Third attempt using Customer configuration, I selected the android simulator - **Failed**
Fourth attempt using Customer configuration, I selected the android simulator - **Successful**!

Not sure what was the reason, there is no change in any setting other than the above (and I am an Administrator of the Mac).

Answer (score 0):

Below steps fixed the problem for me - 
 1. Download zip file from this [location](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6306047.zip)
 2. Extract it and move the emulator folder [image for emulator folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV6Dx.png) into the SDK folder [image for SDK folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcgtF.png)

I hope it works for you as well, I was using **Windows 10 Pro 64bit**

Answer (score 0):

This amount of download requires high speed Internet and if you don't have this it may show this error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the earlier comments, the problem might be because of slow internet connection, just to add more details, you need to download all the problematic file which you get in the logs, in my case they were (emulator-windows_x<>.zip and x86-30_r09.zip) and place them in the respective sub-folders (***PackageOperation02 or PackageOperation05*** ..)  present in **.tmp** folder located under **andriod-sdk** root folder and retrigger the sdk installation from Andriod studio.

What Andriod-Studio will do after your action:
It will first search the files in **.tmp** folder if they exist it wont download and simply unzip and initiate the installation from where it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not had android studio and was using only sdk manager. It was downloading to a location of `<your path>\Android\.temp` Directory.

Deleted the broken .zip file and re-ran the `flutter run` command.

Answer (score -1):

Simply click on menu:  File then click ->Invalidate caches

You may need to check optional if available

(clear file system cache and local history)

(clear vcs log cache and indexes)

Then click Invalidate and Restart.

This will solve your problem.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Same problem happened to me. After two days constant trying I solved the problem. I use internet from my mobile using **JIO SIM**. I just switched my alternate mobile for internet data where I am also using **VODAFONE SIM**. You just switch from your current internet to another internet even over **WIFI**. I see in some cases some websites does not work properly in Jio network otherwise I prefer this network(**JIO**) for its top-notch speed and services. If in your case whatever your data provider just try this method use other data provider or WIFI. If this method solves your problem just hit the like button so others can get help. Thanks