# Cannot download SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I recently made up my mind to develop an Android app.
So I tried to download SDK in Android Studio, but it failed/got stuck all the time with the logs below.

[image: Stuck with the log while downloading components]

**Could anybody tell how to successfully download it**?

My machine specs are shown below:

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8650U

I referred the link below and tried everything in the answers, but none solved my situation.

[Error with SDK package download in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705311/error-with-sdk-package-download-in-android-studio)

Thanks in advance.

-- Added --

This is the result of procmon with filtering "SUCCESS" processes. Possibly "create file" operation caused the problem, but could not find the solution.
(Restarting my PC after disabling antivirus software did not change anything..)

[image: Procmon result]

Comment: Are you sure your antivirus doesn't block any activity? I saw a lot of cases when antivirus messed everything up. Especially for some temp files. Check this tool to debug the issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon . You can find out what's accessing the files during the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I turned off all the antivirus software, but it didn't work. (Changed registry value and turned off windows defender since my PC is managed by my company.) Any further ideas? Thanks anyway @user3417815

Comment: check link with procmon. You can monitor what processes are accessing the files mentioned in your error report. There are plenty of guides over the internet for this. It should give you a clue on what can be done (and what process actually causes the issue)

Comment: Did you reboot your machine after turning off antivirus? In 99% cases it should be done.