# I can not update my android sdk and tools , I have problem with Android Emulator (revision: 30.0.12)

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Packages to install: 
- Android Emulator (emulator)
- Google Play Instant Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)

Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.0.12)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6466327.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Request failed with status code 416.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.0.12)" failed.
Preparing "Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.9.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/iasdk-1.9.0-1566514721.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Instant Development SDK: Request failed with status code 416
"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.9.0)" failed.
Preparing "Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.9.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/iasdk-1.9.0-1566514721.zip
An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Play Instant Development SDK: Request failed with status code 416.
"Install Google Play Instant Development SDK (revision: 1.9.0)" failed.
Failed packages:
- Android Emulator (emulator)
- Google Play Instant Development SDK (extras;google;instantapps)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you add what is your android-studio version, windows version (I guess) and the network you are using (private, public, in company or school, etc )

Comment: Android version is 3.6.3 , I use private network and windows version is 10 Pro @2019

Comment: Did you try with those solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705311/error-with-sdk-package-download-in-android-studio