# Error installing Android Emulator through "SDK Manager", can not manually install either

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run the emulator through Android Studio, I get the message the emulator is not installed, so I try to install it.  Every time I get the following error:
`An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection closed at byte 320157527. Expected 323030753 bytes..`
So, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705311/error-with-sdk-package-download-in-android-studio) solution I tried manually installing the emulator and placing it in the [Android SDK folder]\emulator folder.  Upon doing this, it would still tell me it was missing the emulator & try to install it in [Android SDK folder]\emulator-2, since the "normal" folder existed.

How do you get Android Studio to recognize manually installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I have Android Studio working on another PC.  The only difference I could find between the two installations, was the manual install of the emulator was missing the package.xml file.

I copied this from my other PC & now everything is working perfectly!
I hope this helps someone else, or really me next time I run into this & can't remember how to fix it.